# Delete a very, very deep tree of subdirectories on windows?

Tags: windows, directory, filesystems

I was testing a file management program today and while looking to solve something else my program ended up not checking for moving a directory to the same directory.

The result is a possibly endless recursion of dir1s. I need to commit the changes so I'm desperate to get these out of my repository.

Any ideas?

Basically.. what I got is:

dir/dir/dir/dir........./dir/dir/dir It's probably on the thousands.

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem. There's no way to give solid advice on this question.

Comment: Sorry, I just added an example.

Comment: Related: [Removing an (apparently) infinitely recursive folder](https://serverfault.com/a/667736) - you can pick it apart from the top, like `mv dir1/dir1 tmp` / `rmdir dir1` etc. so you never have to descend into this tree or use long pathnames.  (Or the answers on this question mention some tools that can handle the task.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Are you just trying to delete the directory and all subdirectories?  `RMDIR /S /Q [dirname]` from a command prompt should do the trick.

**Update**
Try this as a workaround:

1. At the top level of the problem directory, create another directory called 'dummy_dir'
2. Run `robocopy dummy_dir problem_dir /purge`

Comment: That doesn't work for me because the directory tree is too long. The problem isn't that there are too many directories in one folder, but thousands of directories nested together.

Comment: Hm, I would expect that command will recursively delete directories.  Can you explain what doesn't work?  Does it give an error?

Comment: It says the directory is not empty. But there is no way it can contain any files (as it never got beyond creating directories). I assume this is because of the depth? I'm not sure myself.

Comment: I just tested RMDIR and it did delete recursively (many levels down).  I have seen RMDIR fail before, and then succeed on subsequent attempts.  There might be a prcoess holding the folder open... you might want to try rebooting and doing RMDIR again.

Comment: I tried again and it now says the dir is too long. Well, my case is pretty extreme, I guess the only solution is formatting the disk.

Comment: Hopefully you haven't formatted yet, try the robocopy workaround.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, JohnD. I also tried the robocopy workaround before the RMDIR one and it just hanged. Either way I am installing the Windows 8 preview so it isn't a big deal. :)

I'm giving you best answer, because most of these solutions probably work with not-so-extreme cases as mine :P

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Robocopy crashes after a minute or so. Any other ideas?

Comment: Accidentally created recursive directories on the production server. Saved my *profanity* :P

Comment: Thank you, this is the only solution that worked for my ultra-nested directory issue. Be careful with your recursive directories on Windows! I had node_modules nested 100 deep somehow.

Answer (score 15):

Install Git Bash or some other form of linux shell emulator.  Works perfectly without any hassle.

rm -rf /c/offending/dir

Comment: Best solution.  I tried several robocopy solutions and they all failed - my folders were too deep.  I even tried a recursive batch file thing.  This was quick, painless, and works exactly as one would expect.

Comment: I tried this on my deep node_modules directory from Git bash, and it errs with : "cannot remove <dir> Directory not empty"

Comment: git bash is a real HERO for windows. Thank you git, thank you Scott

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Meghraj Choudhary for the script to delete the files on windows. 
https://github.com/dev-mraj/fdel

He claims it shortens the path and thus help to delete them
Helpful for node developers

```
npm install fdel -g
fdel ./node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

The robocopy solution works great. Make sure the command line prompt has Admin Rights (you would see "Access denied" msgs, if not).

BTW: When we had a similar problem, i was using the already installed Webserver (Coldfusion) to recursively delete the folder structure accidentally created by another cfm script. The following code could ev. be rewritten in Java or other lang. - as installing a Webserver might be a bit overkill to overcome your issue ;-)

```
<!--- Tag to delete all the wrongly created subdirectories by the buggy search index script version
--->

<cfdirectory directory="webroot" name="dirQuery" type="dir" action="LIST" filter="somefilter" recurse="yes">

<cfloop query="dirQuery">
<cfoutput>#directory#\#name#</cfoutput><br/>
<cftry>
    <cfdirectory action = "delete" directory = "#directory#\#name#" recurse="yes">
<cfcatch>
    <cfoutput>could not delete.</cfoutput><br/>
</cfcatch>
</cftry>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to build a java program to do the job. It is important the Threa.sleep(100) that you will see in the next lines because that lets the Windows OS have time to delete the very deeeeeeep directory.
This worked for me. I had more than 700 child dirs with the same name and in some cases with files inside.

Check it out:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class DelDir {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String path = "C:/your_path/problematic_dir";

        File file = new File(path);
        File[] files = null;
        Stack<File> stack = new Stack<File>();
        do {
            files = file.listFiles();
            if (files != null && files.length > 0){
                if (files.length == 1){
                    stack.push(files[0]);
                    file = files[0];
                    System.out.println(file.getPath());
                } else {
                    for (File afile : files){
                        if (afile.isDirectory()){
                            stack.push(afile);
                            file = afile;
                            System.out.println(file.getPath());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }while(files != null && files.length > 0);
        File toDel;
        boolean del;
        System.out.println(String.format("Files to delete: %1$d", stack.size()));
        while (stack.size() > 0){
            toDel = stack.pop();
            del = toDel.delete();
            Thread.sleep(100);
            if (del){
                System.out.println(String.format("[DELETED:OK] %1$s", toDel.getPath()));
            }else{
                System.out.println(String.format("[DELETED:ERR] %1$s", toDel.getPath()));
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update: Jan 09, 2015 12:49**

So after realizing the hard way that my recursion bug was still there (see original post below) I stumbled across this post: https://superuser.com/a/425666. It involves writing a batch file to perform a `rename move delete repeat`
loop over the problem directory. This actually solves the problem fairly elegantly as it is a top-down delete rather than a bottom-up.

I'd like to note that I tried all of the solutions offered in this thread to no avail. I think I just had a very extreme case (not unlike the OP). The link from superuser.com (above) however performed beautifully.

---

**Original Response**

I had a similar issue today with a recursion bug creating an absurdly huge tree of files in my project structure. It was officially deemed an "undeletable" directory structure in the Microsoft Knowledge Base. (I've since lost the link that I'm quoting there. I if I find it I will update this post to include it.)

Now, I didn't have this structure committed to any repo, but it was grinding my SVN utility and IntelliJ's indexing procedure to complete stand-stills. When I waited long enough both applications eventually bombed out trying to traverse this horrible directory structure.

However, I was able to resolve the issue by simply moving the uppermost directory of the offending directory tree. For example, given this path:

```
.../SomeProject/src/test/resources/com/myCompany/myApp/topOfBadTree/bad/bad/.../bad/...
```

I just created an `_undeletable` directory completely outside my project structure and performed a simple GUI-based Cut and Paste of the `topOfBadTree` folder - meaning I Cut it from my project and Pasted it in the `_undeletable` directory.

Suddenly, IntelliJ and Tortoise SVN were both back to normal, and I was back to debugging. Granted this doesn't necessarily resolve the issue, it sidesteps it, but if the goal is to get the project structure back in order and working again, this should do the trick.

This project and all applications discussed were running on Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit.

I lost a day to this. Hopefully this helps somebody else NOT do the same.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solution works for me. My nested folders are 8000+ deeps at least before any app that counts it crashed too. robocopy crashed on me after 30 minutes or so. What works for me is to create a bat file that will delete these deep nested folders in chunks. The trick is to figure out the repetition pattern within your deep nested.

IE: if your directory structure are `\dirA\dirB\dirC\dirD\dirE\dirF\dirA\dirB\dirC\...`, then your repetition pattern is `\dirA\dirB\dirC\dirD\dirE\dirF\`. Paste that into the the code snippet below. For my problem my repetition pattern is `\demo\demoApp\app\src\main\java\com\utilities\`. There will always be a pattern, so you have to figure this one out, that is how these thing got created in the first place.

After that, make sure you call your script again to recursively divide and destroy these once and for all. Mine is located at `C:\Users\<your user name>\Desktop\deleteRecursive.bat`, so make sure you correctly define your bat file.

Hope this helps.

```
C:

REM  CD define the repetition pattern here!
cd C:\demo\demoApp\app\src\main\java\com\utilities\

REM Move the rest of the problem dir to a temporary parent folder
move /-Y demo C:\b

REM CD to the temp folder
cd C:\b

REM delete the section of problem-dir above
rd /s/q C:\demo

REM Move the rest of problem-dir back to origin
move /-Y C:\b\demo C:\

REM Call the script again until problem directory is gone!
call C:\Users\<your user name>\Desktop\delete.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

In the post of Daniel Santos, just initialize the var del with false and in the next loop add | !del condition:

For example:

```
boolean del = false;
 while (... | !del) {
...
..
.
```

Works FINE!

Answer (score 0):

You may use this VBScript I have created - it works very well!

```
'Recursively Removes Sub Folders from a Deep Nested Folder Structure.
'By C.Diphoorn March 2020
'
'Usage: cscript RemoveNestedFolders.vbs
'
'  Copy This script to the base of the Folder Structure.
'  If the Script fails as the subfolders are not deep enough then increase the MaxLimit Variable

If UCase( Right( WScript.FullName, 12 ) ) <> "\CSCRIPT.EXE" Then
    X=MsgBox("This script must be run from Admin Command Prompt." & VbCrLf &"Usage: cscript.exe " & WScript.ScriptName )
        wscript.quit
end if

Dim fso,oShell, stdout,a,b,Length, SleepSpeed,f,ff

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Set stdout = fso.GetStandardStream (1)

StartFolder=oShell.CurrentDirectory

RecursiveSubFolder=""
SleepSpeed = 500
MaxLimit = 99999

' Display the current folders in the current directory
WScript.echo "*** Warning you are about to remove subfolders from within this current folder!"
WScript.echo ""
SET f = fso.GetFolder(StartFolder)  
SET ff = f.SubFolders 
For Each f1 in ff   
      wscript.echo " " & f1.name
Next  

WScript.echo ""
WScript.echo "Enter the Subfolder Name to Remove:"
RecursiveSubFolder = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine

if RecursiveSubFolder <> "" then 

   if fso.FolderExists(StartFolder+"\"+RecursiveSubFolder) then 

      oShell.CurrentDirectory = StartFolder

     'Max Length of sub folder path of 255 characters
     Length=int((255-len(StartFolder)) /(len(RecursiveSubFolder)+1))
     if Length <= 0 then Length =1

     a=1
     on error resume next
     Err.Clear
     do
       oShell.CurrentDirectory = ".\" & RecursiveSubFolder
       if Err.Number >0 then exit do
       a=a+1
       wscript.echo  a
     loop until a>=MaxLimit
     on error goto 0

     ' Now move back and remove all subfolders undeath it
     do
       for b = 1 to length
           oShell.CurrentDirectory = ".."
           if oShell.CurrentDirectory = StartFolder then exit for
       next 

       FSO.DeleteFolder(RecursiveSubFolder),true

      ' Wait a Sec to ensure the operating system has a chnace to remove the sub folders
       wscript.sleep(SleepSpeed)
      a=a-Length
      wscript.echo  a
    loop until a<=1 or oShell.CurrentDirectory = StartFolder

    wscript.echo "Complete."
    else
    wscript.echo "Folder: " & StartFolder & "\" & RecursiveSubFolder & " Not Found."
    end if
  else

end if

Set oShell = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
Set stdout = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the folder to delete is `C:\Some Folder`.

The fastest way to delete the folder recursively is this:

```
rd /S /Q '\\?\C:\Some Folder'
```

The disk has to be local for this to work fast (i.e. no mapped network drive);
no wild card characters are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Bash installed, (I am using GIT Bash) you can use

```
rm -r dir
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows Subsystem for Linux installed, you can run the `wsl` command from your CLI which should drop you immediately into a busybox shell. In my case even the present working directory was retained. All you have to do after this is `rm -rv FOLDERNAME` and you'll see the folders getting deleted.

`rm` is the remove command from the *nix world.
`-r` recurses subidirectories
`-v` shows you verbose output, so that you can see the directories getting deleted as they go by.